# Navigation on Custom Post Type Navigation

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called The Standard (the-standard). I'm trying to build an archive page that with a max of 12 posts per page.  I'm having a hard time getting the navigation/pagination to show up.

```
<section class='no-padding-top border-bottom triple-margin-bottom triple-padding-bottom'>
 <div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
   <div class='col-md-1'></div>
   <div class='col-md-10 text-center'>
    <?php
     $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'the-standard',
      'orderby' => 'asc',
      'posts_per_page' => 12,
      'paged' => $paged,
      );
       $issues = new WP_Query( $args );
       if( $issues->have_posts() ) {
        while( $issues->have_posts() ) {
         $issues->the_post();
      ?>
      <p><?php the_date();?><br />
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class='no-margin bold-font-name'><?php the_title (); ?></span> - <?php the_field('page-subheader'); ?></a>              
      </p>
      <?php
          }
        }
        else {
          echo 'Nothing to see here. Keep moving.';
        }
      ?>
      <p class='pull-left'><?php previous_posts_link('Next'); ?></p>
      <p class='pull-right'><?php next_posts_link('Previous'); ?></p>
    </div>
    </div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Rather than creating a new WP_Query in a page template, try creating an archive template for that post type (name it `archive-the-standard.php` and modify the existing archive query for that post type instead of "rolling your own").  this makes pagination much easier

Comment: look into the `pre_get_posts` action hook and `$query->set` function to modify main query

Comment: Ennui, thanks for the tip. Do you know where I can find some documentation on setting up an archive page with the appropriate query?

Comment: check out the Template Heirarchy article on the WP Codex.  But I'll submit an answer that should solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function modify_cpt_archive($query) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('the-standard')) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'the-standard');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
        $query->set('posts_per_page', '12');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'modify_cpt_archive');
```

Add this to your theme (or child theme) `functions.php` file.

This function uses the `pre_get_posts` hook which calls it after the query object is created but before the actual query is run, allowing you to modify the default query.  The conditional statements ensure it only affects front-end custom post type archive pages (otherwise it will affect ALL default queries), then modifies the desired query parameters and returns the updated query object.